# Run network command on start of computer

Tags: windows, networking, script, group-policy

i need to run a command at the start of Windows 10. I've tried good'ol GPO Startup Script and a GPP scheduled task (trigger: on start)

Both times the script is executed, but as the script needs a network connection the script fails. The called executables must be stored on a share.

The GPO "always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" is enabled.

It seems "the network" isn't ready at the time the script gets executed.

```
C:\> ping dc
Ping-Anforderung konnte Host "dc" nicht finden. Überprfen Sie den Namen, und     versuchen Sie es erneut.
```

same with ip

```
C:\> ping 192.168.0.1 -n 1
Ping wird ausgeführt für 192.168.0.1 mit 32 Bytes Daten:
PING: Fehler bei der Üertragung. Allgemeiner Fehler. 

Ping-Statistik fr 192.168.0.1:
Pakete: Gesendet = 1, Empfangen = 0, Verloren = 1
(100% Verlust),
```

What are my posibilitys?

Comment: Could be a few things, we need more info.  What kind of network connection is it?  If WiFi, is it configured to connect at startup?  If wired, does the network adapter have a "wait for link" setting?  Have you attempted to use the "Always wait for the network at computer startup and logon" GP?

Comment: Its wired and the "Always wait ..." GOP is enabled. "Wait for Link" was set to "Auto-Detect".

Comment: If "Wait for Link" is set to "on" it takes much longer before a network connection can be established. So i think "Auto-Detect" equals "off".

Comment: Sounds like you are using a domain controller and you tried setting local group policies. Considered using logon scripts on the domain controller end?

Comment: "If "Wait for Link" is set to "on" it takes much longer before a network connection can be established"  That's the idea. :)  You want it ON, or else the machine may boot before the network is ready.  We ran into this with a bunch of Lenovo desktops we have, in combination with slow-to-negotiate HP switches... if we don't set it to Wait For Link to be ON, the computer-level GPOs don't apply (and as you suggest, "Auto" tends to pick "Off").

Comment: @LPChip of course i'm using a domain controller, but the GPO is applied to a client. And the problem occur on the client.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 ok, i will try and see whether it gets better. I will report.

Comment: @Sinky don't get me wrong here. The Domain Controller does Group Policy, but if you locally use gpedit.msc you can change group policies there too with weird effects. I'm just making sure because you could have been using the local gpedit.msc where you shouldn't, but didn't know.

Comment: Current problem is, only 5 of +20 (win10) workstations have "Wait for Link" driver option.